# How to fix my navigation and footer?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

The nav takes the full screen width and the footer is sticking to the left. Both is wrong and I would like to have the navigation a width of 90% and both be centered. I hope I described the problem comprehensibly.

html code:

```css
@media only screen
 and (device-width: 3840px) 
 and (device-height: 2160px)
 and (orientation: landscape) {

  body {
           width: 90%;
          font-size: 300%;
      }

  .mainHeader img.Margrit {
   height: auto;
   width: 12%;
   top: 20%;
  }

  .mainHeader img.Logo {
   height: auto;  
   width: 12%;
   top: 60%;
  }

  .mainHeader img.Couture {
   height: auto;
   left: 0%;
   top: -18%;
   width: 75%;
  }

  .mainHeader nav {
    width: 90%;
          height: 100px;
      }
      
       .mainHeader nav ul {
  padding-left: 0;
  }

    .mainHeader nav ul li {
  width: 25%;
  text-align: center;
  }

    .mainHeader nav a:link, .mainHeader nav a:visited {
  padding: 20px 367px;
  height: 59px;
     display: inline-block;
  }
      
  .mainFooter {
   display: table;
   height: 100px;
   width: 90%;
   text-align: center;
  }

       .mainFooter p {
    display: table-cell;
       vertical-align: middle;
          text-align: left;
    padding-left: 1%;
       }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
    <head>
  <title>Couture Anni</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/style.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Coming+Soon" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
  <header class="mainHeader">
   <img class="Logo" src="resources/img/Content_variation_800_e.png" alt="Logo">
   <img class="Margrit" src="resources/img/IMG_5347_small.jpg" alt="Annamaria Hofstetter">
   <img class="Couture" src="resources/img/Content_variation_800_g.png" alt="Couture Anni">
   
   <nav>
    
    <ul>
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
                </ul>
    
      </nav>
  </header>
  
  
        
        <footer class="mainFooter">
            <p>Copyright &copy; <a href="#" title="couture-anni">couture-anni.ch</a></p>
        </footer>
        
    </body>


</html>
```

I chose this query because it reproduces the problem. At least I think.

Comment: can you add some html so we can see the issue?

Comment: Im currently ob mobile so i cant give the code here but here is a link to my site you can inspect there https://www.couture-anni.ch

Comment: `.mainFooter {  left: 0; right: 0; margin: auto; }`

Comment: unfortunately this did not fix it for me or to be precise my uhd screen

Comment: Use `max-width` or `min-width` instead

Answer (score 0):

You should keep the body element at 100% and size the other contents from there. margin: 0 auto; takes care of centering your element.

```
body{
  width: 100%;
}
.mainHeader{
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.mainFooter{
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 3%;
}
.mainFooter .footerBody{
  width: 90%;
  margin:0 auto;
  height: 40px;
  clear: both;
  text-align: left;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #9cb34f;
}
.mainFooter .footerBody p {
   display: table-cell;
   vertical-align: middle;
   text-align: left;
   padding-left: 1%;
   margin-top: 0;
 }
```

As for your footer, use the mainFooter class as the wrapper for the fixed positioning, then add a 90% sized container inside that and set display: block;

```
<footer class="mainFooter">
  <div class="footerBody">
    <p>Copyright © <a href="#" title="couture-anni">couture-anni.ch</a></p>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for answering . On my pc screen it worked before and it works now but not when i drag the window on my uhd tv I still get what i described above

Comment: tv screen? are you viewing through a browser from a smart tv? it could be caching issue then